# Reinforcement learning with multiple agents

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am starting a project which involves multiple agents, some that play on the same team and others that play on the opponent's team.

Since I am rather new to this topic, I did some research to get an overview of reinforcement learning.
Now, I have more questions than before.
Especially on the "architecture" and general approach.
When I think of one agent in an environment with a certain goal, it seems to be not so hard to build the proper project. There is an excellent "snake game" video series on YouTube.

But how do you approach the problem when multiple agents are involved?
And how about when you have a variable amount of agents?

Is it good to assign roles to the agents, and then use special trained models for each role? And what about when agents dynamically change their role?

Think of a soccer game where there are three players in a team, and depending on the location of the player, it gets a role assigned.

What about when agents are not only virtual, but they are also physically separated. Is it better that each instance of role/agent uses an own model, or all of them use the same model?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok i see, i am asking multiple questions already :)